# No Internet access after successful failover?

Tags: networking, failover, pfsense

I am using pfSense 2.0.2 and want to set up a failover between my normal WAN connection (GW_WAN) and a 3G surfstick (GW_OPT8).
I put both in a gateway group called WAN_FAILOVER:

```
GW_WAN  Tier1 (Monitor IP 8.8.4.4)
GW_OPT8 Tier2 (Monitor IP 8.8.8.8)
```

Trigger level is member down.

Additionally I enabled "Allow default gateway switching" in System - Advanced - Miscellaneous. 
In the firewall rules on the VLAN interface where my compuster is connected to, I have set the WAN_FAILOVER group as gateway.

For testing the failover I removed the WAN (GW_WAN) ethernet cable. System log then looks like this:

```
Jan 12 19:42:32     php: : MONITOR: GW_WAN is down, removing from routing group
Jan 12 19:42:32     php: : Default gateway down setting GW_OPT8 as default!
Jan 12 19:42:19     apinger: ALARM: GW_WAN(8.8.4.4) *** down ***
```

Routing table also gets updated:

```
default     10.64.64.0  UGS     0   184     1492    ppp0
```

Any idea why it isn't working? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I meanwhile foudn the error: On Firewall: NAT: Outbound the manual rule creation was enabled (needed e.g. if one wants static ports, useful for VoIP). There I only had rules for the normal WAN interface, duplicating those rules and replacing the WAN interface with the failover interface made everything work :-) Also one doesn't need the gateway group and WAN_FAILOVER group as gateway in the firewall rules when having only 2 WAN interfaces. I guess those options are for more advanced things, e.g. 3 WAN interfaces where it isn't clear which one shall be used when the primary one fails.